# Project Tango DepthBuffer order?

Tags: google-project-tango

Depth information of scene is obtained as FloatBuffer from `xyzIj.xyz`function. I want to apply k-nearest neighbor method to filter 3D point cloud data. To search for neighbors within boundary, 3D points have to be arranged. Do 3D coordinates in FloatBuffer follow any order?

Comment: There's no order in FloatBuffer. But one observation being, if we take a set of ~10 points, they are relatively adjacent to each other. For applications like finding a local normal, this feature is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the xyzIj is not ordered. You will have to project it onto a image plane to file the adjacent points.